# Conditions for deleting a question?

Tags: discussion

I was trying to delete my question but not able to do so. Can someone tell me the conditions of deleting a question??

Answer (score 5):

First of all, by posting a question (or an answer) on Stack Exchange you have agreed to the [Terms of Service](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/legal/terms-of-service#licensing) which state:

> #### Subscriber Content
>
> You agree that any and all content, including without limitation any and all text, graphics, logos, tools, photographs, images, illustrations, software or source code, audio and video, animations, and product feedback (collectively, “Content”) that you provide to the public Network (collectively, “Subscriber Content”), is perpetually and irrevocably licensed to Stack Overflow on a worldwide, royalty-free, non-exclusive basis pursuant to Creative Commons licensing terms ([CC BY-SA 4.0](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0/)), and you grant Stack Overflow the perpetual and irrevocable right and license to access, use, process, copy, distribute, export, display and to commercially exploit such Subscriber Content, even if such Subscriber Content has been contributed and subsequently removed by you

That means you can't delete a question just because e.g. you feel embarrassed for asking it. Since you indicate you can't delete it, it [probably has an upvoted answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5222/295232) - the linked FAQ has all the details in the section "When can't I delete my own post?". Suppose that you would delete the question: then the answer would be gone too, even though it is (apparently) a good answer, and somebody put in the (or even *a lot of*) effort to write it. That would not be fair, would it?

There is a way to [disassociate the post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/96732/295232) from your account but it should be used sparingly; if you do repeated requests like that, you might get suspended.

Comment: More generally, a lot of features of Stack Exchange were counterintuitive to me until I understood one thing: The primary purpose of the site is to build a library of questions and answers for future researchers, and helping people asking the question is secondary to that.  This explains some features that would otherwise seem bizarre (for example, the fact that power users can edit your posts without your consent (!), and it's also the reason why you can't delete your own posts).

Answer (score 2):

Rephrasing the [FAQ](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5222/312026) post, you can delete your question if all of the following apply:

- There is no more than one answer; **and**
- You did not accept that answer; **and**
- The answer does not have a positive score; **and**
- No bounty is currently applied on the question or has been given to the answer; **and**
- You are a registered user (not a guest account).

In your case, as of writing this your account lists 4 questions, of which 2 fail condition one, 3 fail condition two and 3 fail condition three rendering all your current questions save one undeletable.

The reasoning behind this is that by deleting a question with an answer that gave the poster reputation you would be harming that person without them being able to do anything about it and in spite of effort they put in. In the case of multiple answers it is less clear but likely due to an idea of ‘one of them has to be better, doesn’t it?’ or something like that.